# jqplot: legend data format for barchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I am unable to create legend with all items I need for given jqplot.

I am using jqplot firs time and it was difficult for me to dreate barchart data array in correct format. I have come to the solution, but not I do not have legend labels as I need.

```
var chartData = [
    [
        ['Portfolio Risk', 1],
        ['Model Risk', 4],
        ['Recovery Risk', 1],
        ['Capability Risk', 1],
        ['Process Risk', 1],
        ['Forward flow risk', 5]
    ]
];

//var ticks = ['Portfolio Risk'], ['Model Risk'], ['Recovery Risk'], ['Process Risk'], ['Forward flow risk'];

plot2 = $.jqplot('chart1', chartData, {
    seriesColors: ['#85802b', '#00749F', '#73C774', '#C7754C', '#17BDB8'],
    seriesDefaults: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        rendererOptions: {
            // Set the varyBarColor option to true to use different colors for each bar.
            // The default series colors are used.
            varyBarColor: true
        }
    },
    axesDefaults: {
        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
        tickOptions: {
            fontSize: '10pt'
        }
    },
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            tickOptions: {
                angle: 90
            },
            //ticks: ticks

        },
        yaxis: {
            //renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer                    
            tickOptions: {
                stringFormat: "%d"
            }
        },
    },
    legend: {
        show: true,
        placement: 'outside',
        //labels: ticks
    },
});
```

JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/renatevidruska/7dn86/
You can see missing labels in legend (there should be more items).
I was trying to create `ticks` array using different formats, no success.

Comment: there is only 1 series you have thats why you are seeing only 1 legend item.

Comment: can you help me to fix this? I mean, can you show me the correct way to define chartData? I need 6 bars, each in different color and representing its own item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tick is not rotate because you didn't include some of `<script>`. Please see [an example of tick](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/rotated-tick-labels.php).

And your legend is missing some of labels becuase your `chartData`(array) is not correct. [Here is an example of legend](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/blockPlot.html).

Here is the working code. http://jsfiddle.net/7dn86/3/

Comment: This is nice, but is there a way to define everything in one array instead of series1, series2 etc. This would be much more easier as data are coming from server side and I do not want to create five or even more different variables.

Comment: It seems I can define it like this: var series = [[['Portfolio Risk', 1]], [['Model Risk', 4]], [['Recovery Risk', 1]],[['Capability Risk', 1]], [['Forward flow risk', 5]]];, is it right?

Comment: Another thing that legend doesn't have the same values as labels, how to fix this?

Comment: @renathy Your second comment is correct! And did you ask about how to change the label of legend?

Comment: I fixed legend creating additional array for legend. Now I have problem that I am not able to make all bars to be in the center. For example, in your example first bar is situated on the left side, but all bars should be centered.